# How to prove the following linear regression properties?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, regression-coefficients, linear

Why is it that the below are true?

1. $\sum_{i=1}^n \hat{y}_ie_i= 0$

so far, I have, for the above: $\sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{y_i})(y_i-\hat{y_i})=0$

= $\sum_{i=1}^n \hat{y_i} y_i- \hat{y_i}^2$
so does the first term after the summation equal the squared $\hat{y_i}$ term? May be explained by some linear algebra, but not sure.

2. $\sum_{i=1}^nx_ie_i= 0$